# how to refer a properties file in Java project

Tags: java, junit, classpath

I have a Node.properties file placed in the config folder of my Java project. The hierarchy of the folder is :

```
**Project**
   ->src
   ->config
      ->client
      ->eclipse
          ->test
      ->preferences
```

When I build the code successfully and try to run a test class using JUNIT, I get an error -

```
Node.properties not found in classpath
```

I have checked the classpath file and found that while the path `/config/eclipse/test` is referred, the files in `/config/client` are not being referred.

Could you please let me know how can I ensure that the file is found in classpath?

I am using Ant script to build the project in Eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some more information. What build tool do you use? What kind of project (Eclipse, Netbeans, etc.) do you have?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I have added the details. Kindly check.

Comment: if you are running from eclipse, you can add the required folders to the classpath in the Run/Debug settings of your eclipse project properties.

Comment: @KiranMohan I have explicitly added the properties file in the Eclipse classpath in External Configurations. But I get the same error

Comment: ..consider using Maven project layout?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running eclipse

1. Rt click on the project -> select properties
2. Click `Java Build Path`
3. Under `Source` tab
   Add the path `config/client`